# "Hello World" with MAMP server and PHP

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm beginning a new job and I need to make lots of things with MAMP.
I read the documentation about MAMP and some movies/tutorials.

I configured my server (ports, ...) and I created a little php file : HelloWorld.php

So I want to read this file on my server but I don't get a correct result :/

When I launch MAMP or MAMP Pro, I get a page "It works !" with localhost. But when I launch :

> localhost:80/MAMP/htdocs/HelloWorld.php

I get a 404 not found error

My php file looks like :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World en PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php echo 'Hello World !'; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you if you can help me ;)

Comment: I made : copy the path and I paste it in the search bar but it doesn't work, very strange

Comment: Try just using localhost:80/HelloWorld.php

Comment: @AndrewL The requested URL /HelloWorld.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Sorry, I've got nothing

Comment: @AndrewL My php file is located there : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/HelloWorld.php

Comment: So use `http://localhost:80/test/HelloWorld.php`. The URL is relative to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`, which is your document root

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you to your answer :) It works and I clicked on the tab "my website" on MAMP homepage and it's good :)